# C# Razor List to JSON: Get value by key

Tags: c#, json, razor

I am pulling data from a database on a Razor page and putting it in a list. The intention is for the user to type in a year, and the Make of the car should pop up.

C#

```
List<string[]> ListOfAutoMakes = new List<string[]>();
foreach (var item in SQDB.Query("SELECT year, make FROM cars"))
{
    string[] AutoMakes = new string[2];
    AutoMakes [0] = item.id.Trim();
    AutoMakes [1] = item.make.Trim();
    ListOfAutoMakes.Add(AutoMakes);
}
```

The Javascript in the cshtml file:

```
var AutoMakeList = '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListOfAutoMakes.ToArray()))';
alert(AutoMakeList.1983 + ' ' + AutoMakeList['1991'])
```

The rendered Javascript shows my data looks like this:

```
var AutoMakeList = '[["1983","VOLVO"],["1991","FIAT"],["1982","VOLVO"]]'
```

And the output is `Undefined` or an empty string.

Obviously, I am not getting a Key/Value pair. I am certain the issue is in how I am building my C# List, but I am not sure how I should be creating it. I'm a noob with C#, but I believe I am building an array of arrays when I really need to build a dictionary. I've spent the day googling creating a C# dictionary, serializing it to JSON, then accessing the resulting JSON via an Key. All the examples I find are either for older/other versions of C# or not complete enough for me to connect all the dots.

Comment: You don't need a dictionary, you have a database.  If you're using Web API write a Get method that calls 'SELECT make FROM cars WHERE year = @year'.

Comment: Why not try using a Dictionary yourself first and post any errors you are running into ?

Comment: Your json data is array not object so I think you can't use key/value to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your current JSON data is an array not object so I think you can't use key/value to do it.

if you want to use JSON key/value in Javascript.

You can try to create a `AutoMakes` class instead of `string[2]` to carry your data.

```
public class AutoMakes
{

    public string id { get; set; }
    public string make { get; set; }
}
```

then you can do it like, `SerializeObject` in controller carry the JSON with string.

```
List<AutoMakes> ListOfAutoMakes = new List<AutoMakes>();
foreach (var item in SQDB.Query("SELECT year, make FROM cars"))
{
    ListOfAutoMakes.Add(new AutoMakes()
    {
        id = item.id.Trim(),
        make = item.make.Trim()
    });
}
ViewBag.ListOfAutoMakes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListOfAutoMakes);
```

then you can show array first object key=`id` value.

```
var AutoMakeList = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ListOfAutoMakes);
alert(AutoMakeList[0].id);
```

[Here is a sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eMmM5X)

**Note**

I would use ajax to call the JSON data instead of use razor, becasue that will be More flexible.